# "FileUtils.cp" not working correctly -ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Script which do the following (my Problem is in step 5):

1. Go recursively through some directories,  parse xml files and store the results into array
2. Create a new directory "new_directory" within each of the directories where the xml files are placed
3. Do the same like in 2) but create text files "temp.txt"
4. Open the temp.txt and write the parsing results into it. The strings written to "temp.txt" are paths to source files, like following:

   ```
   ../../Path/to/source/source_a.c
   ../../Path/to/othersource/source_b.c
   ```
5. And with the last step I try to copy these source files from temp.txt into the new directory "new_directory"

The code looks like this:

```
#######--STEP 1) 
    xml_files = Dir['TESTS_*/**/*.xml']
    xml_files.each do |file_name|

      ##parsing logic is here.... I didn't show it---

      $my_array = []

#######--STEP 2) 
      xml_directory = Dir['TESTS_*/*/']
      xml_directory.each do |folder|
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(folder, 'new_Directory'))
      end

#######--STEP 3) 
      tmp_file = File.expand_path(File.dirname(file_name)) + "/temp.txt"

#######--STEP 4) 
      File.open(tmp_file, 'w') {|f| f.write $my_array.join("\n")}

#######--STEP 5) 
      tmp_file.each_line do |file_name |
        FileUtils.cp(file_name, 'new_Directory')   
      end
    end
```

Everything is done fine, but the source files from the "temp.txt" file are not copied. There is no error. Is the problem maybe in step 3) by creating the temp.txt file? This way of creating files and than writing to them I have done in other scripts and it worked.When I  print "p tmp_file" I get this:

```
"C:/Project/TESTS_A/myTestsA/temp.txt"
"C:/Project/TESTS_B/myTestsB/temp.txt"
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Move STEP2:

```
xml_directory = Dir['TESTS_*/*/']
xml_directory.each do |folder|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(folder, 'new_Directory'))
end
```

out of topmost `Dir[...]` (before it). The reason is that `Dir#[]` changes `Dir.pwd` and, being nested, the block above just returns empty set. since it is being executed *relatively* to current directory.

To check what’s going on yourself, try to `puts Dir.pwd` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @mudasobwa:

As first, I forgot a line in my question, exactly within step 2) . The original one was:

```
#######--STEP 2) 
Dir.chdir ../../../../ do
      xml_directory = Dir['TESTS_*/*/']
      xml_directory.each do |folder|
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(folder, 'new_Directory'))
      end
```

As you can see I changed the working directory (../../../../) of the ruby script on the wrong place and this was the problem. So I should change the working directory within step 5) so that the code looks like:

```
#######--STEP 5) 
Dir.chdir ../../../../ do      
tmp_file.each_line do |file_name |
        FileUtils.cp(file_name, 'new_Directory')   
      end
    end
```

Comment: One should not post this as another answer.